# Using bottle.py to print on browser

Tags: python, function, printing, bottle

I am new to python and especially in using modules.I have to use bottle.py module . Is there any possible way to print something in my browser , without having to return it ? To be more specific , I want something like this:

```
import pymysql
from bottle import Bottle,run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/conn')
def conn():
    **print("Trying to connect to database...")**
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(user="X",passwd="X",host="X",port=X,database="X")
    return "Connection succeded"
except:
    return "Oops...connection failed"

run(app, host='localhost',port = 8080)
```

How can I print something like "Trying to connect to database without having to return it ?

Comment: Using javascript in your template is the right way to do that.

Comment: @Spade I must only use python+sql with  bottle.py only avaible !

Comment: There is no way to do that! Since you're sending data back to client, you need a new request to answer that request.

Comment: What you're trying to do is update a web-page without having to reload it. This is why AJAX exists. Bottle is not a UI framework - it only lets you define your controllers and connect them to your views. What happens in your view should be managed separately.

Comment: Hmmm ok I guess...Any suggestions for the present situation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print` syntax/function will only display on stdout not on the browser.  Use `yield` instead of `return` to "gradually display content" (for lack of better words).  I used to favor Bottle over Flask for this very reason (Flask has a different way of doing it though).

```
import pymysql
from bottle import Bottle,run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/conn')
def conn():
    yield "Trying to connect to database..."
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(user="X",passwd="X",host="X",port=X,database="X")
        yield "Connection succeded"
    except:
        yield "Oops...connection failed"

run(app, host='localhost',port = 8080)
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I never knew. Is this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html.  Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote :D I needs the points!

Comment: Had been thinking of ditching bottle for flask but hadn't explored async abilities yet. This is good - take my upvote.

Comment: Whoops @Spade I thought you were the one who asked the question :D. In any case, thanks for the upvote!